# Return Promise from Ractivejs-Adaptor

Tags: javascript, promise, ractivejs

i wrote a RactiveJS Adaptor which syncs the object with a [json-api](http://jsonapi.org/). I'd like to respond to the resolved Promise from ractive, but the ractive.set-method resolves as soon as the property is set and doesn't wait for my adaptor.set-method to resolve.

the adaptor-class:

```
JsonApiWrapper.prototype = {
    /**
     * Update object if model-id changes
     * @param prop
     * @param value
     */
    set: function (prop, value) {
        if (prop === '_id' && !this.updatelock) {
            this.updatelock = true;
            return this.jsonapi.find(value)
                .then(function (data) {
                    return this.ractive.set(this.prefixer(data));
                }.bind(this))
                .then(function(){
                    /**
                     * release updatelock
                     * @type {boolean}
                     */
                    this.updatelock = false;
                    return this.object;
                }.bind(this))
        } else {
            this.object[prop] = value;
            return Promise.resolve(this.object);
        }
    },
```

the call from the ractive:

```
 this.set('poll._id', id).then(function(){
           /**
             * Check if poll is voted
             */
            if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
                if (localStorage.getItem('polls-'+this.get('poll._id'))) {
                    this.set('poll.status', 'inactive');
                }
            }
 });
```

the "then" from the second code resolves as soon as the property is set and not after the fetch resolved.

is this a bug, a feature or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: not sure what you are referring to as *the fetch* ... your set function doesn't always return a Promise (e.g. in the else code) so it's doomed to failure

Comment: also, `return Promise.resolve(this.object);` where you are using it (in a then callback) is redundant, just `return this.object;` will do

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, @JaromandaX . I edited the source example accordingly.

with `this.jsonapi.find` is a json library using es6-fetch as request library and always returns Promises.

Comment: This line looks off: `return this.ractive.set(this.prefixer(data));`. Are you meaning to set each of the keys of data as a key? Or are you trying to assign the value of data to `this.keypath`, ie `return this.ractive.set(this.keypath, data)`?

Comment: Also, if you use `ractive.update` instead of `ractive.set`, then you don't need to implement a lock to prevent re-entrant call to `set` on your adaptor.

Comment: [ractive.set(Map)](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-set) is absolutely legit and in difference to ractive.update doesn't teardown und reset the whole object (which breaks all subscriptions/listeners).

Comment: good suggestions regarding the code itself, but still no answer to my question :(

to make it clear: the code works as assumed, but the Promise of the Adaptor doesn't bubble to the `ractive.set()` in the second snippet.